# While running test classes using jest.spyOn my test is failing

Tags: jestjs, salesforce

Here is my test class while testing this i am getting error:

````
describe('some default check', () => {

   let serverObj: http.Server;
   let jwtToken: string; 
    beforeAll(async()=> {
        setGracefulCleanup();
        serverObj = beforeEach();

        await request(serverObj)
            .post('/api/authUser')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .send({accessToken: 'accessToken'})
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect((response: any) => {
                jwtToken = response.body.data.token;
                
            });
    });

    afterAll(() => { 
        serverObj = afterEach();
        setGracefulCleanup();
    });

    test('it should get the correct default base class json response for no response from org',async()=>{
        let sfSeedObject: SfConnectionManagerSpec;
        sfSeedObject = new SfConnectionManagerSpec();
        const value = SfConnectionManager.getConnectionByParams(sfSeedObject.sfConnectionObject);
        
        const spySfConnectionManager = jest.spyOn(SfConnectionManager, 'getConnectionByParams').mockImplementation(()=> value);
        console.log('Number of times connection is called:', spySfConnectionManager.mock.calls.length);

        const connection = jest.spyOn(value.tooling,'query').mockImplementationOnce(()=> res);
        console.log('Number of times connection is called:', connection.mock.calls.length);
        console.log("are we getting res",res);

        await request(serverObj)
        .post('/api/sf/getDefaultBaseClassJSON')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('token', jwtToken)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect((response: any) => {
            expect (connection).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(response.body.success).toBeTruthy();
            expect(response.body.data[0].defaultclassName).toEqual('someRecodForm');
            expect(response.body.data).toHaveLength(1)
            expect(response.body.data[0].objects).not.toBeNull();
            expect(response.body.data[0].objects).not.toBeUndefined()
                
        });
    })
}); ```
> here is the res:
````

export const res: any = {
queryLocator: null,
entityTypeName: 'LightningComponentBundle',
records: [ ]
};

```
> and here is the SFcinnectionManagerSpec:
```

export class SfConnectionManagerSpec {
public sfConnectionObject = {
accessToken: 'access token',
instanceUrl: 'instanceURL'
};
}

```
> so my issues write here is i am getting error as while running this test.
```

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0

  59 |         .set('token', jwtToken)
  60 |         .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
> 61 |         .expect((response: any) => {
     |          ^
  62 |             expect (connection).toHaveBeenCalled();
  63 |             expect(response.body.success).toBeTruthy();
  64 |             expect(response.body.data[0].defaultclassName).toEqual('someRecodForm');
```